# C# SmtpClient connecting to A2 hosting email

Tags: c#, smtp, smtpclient

I am having a very hard time trying to send an email through an a2 hosting account.  I know the code is correct as I have the same code sending emails through the Google SMTP.  I was wondering if anyone had any experience or examples using a2 hosting email and SMTP c#.  I've read through their documentation and it states to use user@hostingdomain.com for the username and then your password. For the server you can use the full domain name or the server name.  For the port it says 587 or 465.  I have tried a combination of all of these things and have not been able to connect.  I keep getting this exception

> "Unable to read data from the transport connection:
>   net_io_connectionclosed."

Thank you for any help.

Below is an example of the code I am using.

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("testuser@mydomain.a2hosted.com");
NetworkCredential myCred = new NetworkCredential(
 "testuser@mydomain.a2hosted.com", "mypassword");

smtpClient.Host = "mydomain.a2hosted.com";
//smtpClient.Credentials = myCred;
smtpClient.Port = 587;
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtpClient.Credentials = myCred;
message.From = fromAddress;
message.Subject = "your subject";
//Set IsBodyHtml to true means you can send HTML email.
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.Body = "<h1>your message body</h1>";
message.To.Add("myemail@gmail.com");

smtpClient.Send(message);
```

Comment: What is your experience if you use other clients? E.G. Thunderbird, or Outlook?

Comment: Does your domain permits less secure apps to access?

Comment: I am able to connect correctly through outlook/mail app.  Must be a setting I am using on smtpclient, but I can't figure out which one it is.

Comment: Have encountered the exact same issue this evening, no matter which combination of port and settings I try it will not send.  Been on their live chat waiting for a response for 35minutes and counting.  Did you resolve your issue @MaxiPereyra?

Comment: I ended up getting it to work but only on port 25.  Which by the way may be blocked by your isp when testing.  I was able to confirm it was a SSL connection so I am fine with using port 25.  For the username use username@domain.com,  For the server make sure you use your server name instead of mail.yourdomain.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All in here.

https://www.a2hosting.co.uk/kb/a2-hosting-products/windows-hosting/using-asp-net-to-send-e-mail-messages#C-example

Replace domain.a2hosted.com with your own domain name.
Replace user@example.com with the name of an e-mail account you created in Plesk.
Replace password with the password for the e-mail account you specified in the previous step.

From my config file.

```
<mailSettings>
      <smtp from="noreply@goldendate.co.uk">
        <network enableSsl="false" 
defaultCredentials="false" host="yourdomain" 
password="yourpassword" port="25" 
userName="youremailaddress" />
</mailSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you work remotely, it'll not work.
You have to upload your code to a2hosting server and then it'll work.